# PHP Unpack a single byte from a binary string

Tags: php, rawstring

I have a raw string of bytes $b coming from

```
$b=sha1($k,true);
```

I need to know the value of $b[$ix]. The only way I've found is

```
$arr=unpack('Cw',$b[$ix]);
$value=$arr["w"];
```

But for such elemental operation it seems too much overload.

Is there a more straight way to access the bytes in a raw string?

Comment: just treat it as an array of bytes: `$foo = 'abc123'; echo $foo[2]` outputs `c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ascii value:

```
$b=sha1($k,true);
echo ord($b[$ix]);
```

Comment: This also works, $b=sha1($k); echo $b[2 * $ix] * 16 + $b[2 * $ix + 1];

Comment: $arr=unpack('C',$b[$ix]);  $value=$arr[1];